# Response code error while running basic google jmeter script

Tags: jmeter

I have scripted a basic script to hit www.google.com with a single user using JMeter. I am experiencing below error everytime I try to execute it. It works fine on my laptop out of office network.

**The sampler Result:**

```
Thread Name: Example test 1-1
Sample Start: 2014-08-22 10:56:03 BST
Load time: 6272
Latency: 0
Size in bytes: 2128
Headers size in bytes: 0
Body size in bytes: 2128
Sample Count: 1
Error Count: 1
Response code: Non HTTP response code: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException
Response message: Non HTTP response message: Connection to http://www.google.com refused

Response headers:


HTTPSampleResult fields:
ContentType: 
DataEncoding: null
```

**Solution to overcome this issue is much appreciated, Thanks in advance.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is an issue with your enterprise proxy.

Read this documentation to configure JMeter with your enterprise proxy parameters:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#proxy_server